# Revit Api - Material with Texture from filepath

Tags: c#, textures, texture-mapping, revit-api, revit

Does anybody know how to create programmatically Revit material and add texture from the file?

Now I'm doing little dirty hack, where I'm searching for "Earth" which is a standard one and changing path file to texture using AssetProperty. Main problem with this solution is situation where I don't have this material in project :P

I only know how to create colored texture:

```
    static public Material CreateColorMaterial(Document doc, Color color, string name, bool isTransparency = false)
    {
        SubTransaction createMaterial = new SubTransaction(doc);
        createMaterial.Start();
        //Try to copy an existing material.  If it is not available, create a new one.
        Material materialNew = GetMaterial(name, doc);
        if (materialNew != null)
        {
            createMaterial.Commit();
            return materialNew;
        }

        ElementId idNew = Material.Create(doc, name);
        materialNew = doc.GetElement(idNew) as Material;

        if(isTransparency)
            materialNew.Transparency = 99;

        materialNew.Color = color;
        createMaterial.Commit();

        SubTransaction createPropertySets = new SubTransaction(doc);
        createPropertySets.Start();

        //Create a new structural asset and set properties on it.
        StructuralAsset structuralAsssetColor = new StructuralAsset("ColorStructuralAsset" + name, Autodesk.Revit.DB.StructuralAssetClass.Generic);
        structuralAsssetColor.DampingRatio = .5;

        PropertySetElement pseStructural = PropertySetElement.Create(doc, structuralAsssetColor);

        //Create a new thermal asset and set properties on it.
        ThermalAsset thermalAssetColor = new ThermalAsset("ColorThermalAsset" + name, Autodesk.Revit.DB.ThermalMaterialType.Solid);
        thermalAssetColor.Porosity = 0.1;
        thermalAssetColor.Permeability = 0.2;
        thermalAssetColor.Compressibility = .5;
        thermalAssetColor.ThermalConductivity = .5;

        //Create PropertySets from assets and assign them to the material.
        PropertySetElement pseThermal = PropertySetElement.Create(doc, thermalAssetColor);
        createPropertySets.Commit();
        SubTransaction setPropertySets = new SubTransaction(doc);
        setPropertySets.Start();
        materialNew.SetMaterialAspectByPropertySet(MaterialAspect.Structural, pseStructural.Id);
        materialNew.SetMaterialAspectByPropertySet(MaterialAspect.Thermal, pseThermal.Id);

        setPropertySets.Commit();
        return materialNew;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does The Building Coder solution for [setting material texture path in `EditScope`](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/04/set-material-texture-path-in-editscope.html) address your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because it is only changing texture on existing material :/ I'm searching the way to create material from scratch

Comment: A Revit API discussion forum thread on [creating a new material and adding new physical and thermal assets](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/create-new-material-and-add-new-physical-and-thermal-assets-with/m-p/7311468) solves that aspect, but does not do anything with the textures... does that help?

Comment: Thanks, I will check this later. In the meantime, I managed this loading prepared template project with the material in the background and copy it to the main document :P It's a dirty hack but working

Comment: Glad to hear it! Congratulations! Here are some other discussions on handling materials in Revit API: https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.5. If you have a new approach to solve this, would you mind sharing it with us as well? Thank you!